# Dates and times in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I understand emacs lisp is great for handling dates and times, but does it have a function to convert strings to internal representation of integers using formats like `%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S,` and so on? And also, in the emacs reference manual, it says that times are lists of two or three integers, but is there a more formal specification or description? ~ Thanks ~

**Edit**: Thanks for the responses - but guess I was wondering if there was a function that does format-time-string in reverse (like `parse-time-string` but with structure specifications for the input string)?

**Edit2**: I guess the answer is that there is nothing built in... but a partial implementation has been implemented [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-zh/StrPTime).

Comment: I just tried strptime.el and it doesn't even work for the "Manual testing" examples given in the file; apparently replace-in-string is no longer in emacs. Too bad, I am looking for the same functionality.

Comment: Does it work if you create an alias `(defalias 'replace-in-string 'replace-regex-in-string)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time is returned by most time related functions as a list of three integers.  The first has the
most significant 16 bits of the seconds, while the second has the
least significant 16 bits.  The third integer gives the microsecond
count.

The microsecond count is zero on systems that do not provide
resolution finer than a second.

As for the rest of your question have a look at [this section](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_689.html) of the manual in case you missed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun encode-time-string (string)
  (apply #'encode-time (parse-time-string string)))
```

The internal representation may change; I think it'd be better to use the provided documented API (encode-time, decode-time, etc) to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse a date (without a time), such as `"July 7, 2022"`, then `parse-time` will return `nil` for the first 3 values. To avoid `Wrong type argument: fixnump, nil`, this possibility should be checked for:

```
(defun encode-time-string (string)
  (let* ((dt (parse-time-string string))
     (dtt (if (car dt)
          dt
        (append '(0 0 0) (nthcdr 3 dt))))
     )
    (apply #'encode-time dtt)))
```